# Time data does not match format python

Tags: python, django

I'm having troubles converting a time string to datetime object:

time data 'June 30, 2016, 11:44 a.m.' does not match format '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p'

```
object = datetime.strptime('June 30, 2016, 11:44 a.m.', '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

> %p    Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. 
>   AM, PM (en_US);
>   am, pm (de_DE)

You need to change "a.m." for am

Maybe:

```
date = 'June 30, 2016, 11:44 a.m.'.replace('a.m.','am').replace('p.m.','pm') 
object = datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that 'a.m.' matches your locale for AM/PM?

what happens if you do

```
object = datetime.strptime('June 30, 2016, 11:44 am', '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

?